# Select multiple dropdown menu - where should i put name="blabla" or How can i bind data

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

[dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzYXj.png)

I've created dropdown menu where user can select multiple genres.
However, I want to send data as pipeline binded. (as below)
**`aaa.com/genre=Action|Adventure`**
or alternatively **%7C** instead of **|**

This is my html

```
<div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                    id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                Select genre(s)
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li ><label><input value="Action" type="checkbox">Action</label></li>
```

If i set **`name="genre"`** here,

`<li ><label><input name="genre" value="Action" type="checkbox">Action</label></li>`

it sends multiple selected values like this :
**`aaa.com/genre=Action&genre=Adventure`**

not this one  **`aaa.com/genre=Action|Adventure`**

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by putting hidden input and changing the val of that input by id (and whenever selection occurs)